# Problems with stem - can't stem correctly, and with identify in R using plot

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the `stem` function to create a stem and leaf plot, but as far as I know it isn't working good, and I don't know why.

I'm doing something like this:

```
d= c(60,85,72,59,37,75,93,7,98,63,41,90,5,17,97)

stem(d,scale=1)
```

And I'm getting stem like this:

```
  0 | 577
  2 | 7
  4 | 19
  6 | 0325
  8 | 50378
```

As far as I know there isn't any 27 value in `d`, or two times 7 value...

It's working weirdly and incorrect, and I don't know why. Additionally, I know that there should be one more column with numbers of observation, and my stem doesn't have it...

Comment: I suggest you move the second and apprently unrelated question into a second post. It's not good practice to have two questions in one post. - it's the sort of thing that can see your question get closed even if it's a perfectly good question otherwise.

Comment: thanks! I will do two threads instead all questions in one thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is being collapsed into groups of 20, not 10. You can see that the stem portion goes up in 2s, so all data are collapsed into groups represented in the stem steps.

If you lengthen the plot with scale, e.g. `stem(d, scale = 2)` this becomes obvious, and the diagram looks more obviously correct. You can see that what looks like a '27' in your plot above, is actually the 37.

```
  0 | 57
  1 | 7
  2 | 
  3 | 7
  4 | 1
  5 | 9
  6 | 03
  7 | 25
  8 | 5
  9 | 0378
```